# Restrict access to path in the URL

Tags: angular, html, reactjs, react-router

If I have a URL "http://somesite.com/root/folder/subdirectory/myfile.pdf" 
How can I make sure the user can access the full URL to view and download myfile.pdf but not have access to "http://somesite.com/root" or "http://somesite.com/root/folder" or "http://somesite.com/root/folder/subdirectory"??

The implement can be in HTML, angular 6, reactjs or any such frameworks.

Comment: in IIS you can do that by setting the directoryBrowsing to false

Comment: Thanks... Can that be enabled on client?? Just thinking if there can be any security loophole.

Comment: no, the endpoint user can only access the files that he knows the absolute urls! for instance if the user knows that you have a file named test.pdf and it is available on this path: `http://somesite.com/root/folder/subdirectory/test.pdf` then he can access it by chance

Answer (score 0):

You can define a route which will fetch the pdf for you.

```
http://somesite.com/root/folder/subdirectory/test.pdf
```

In the component for this route you can fetch pdf based on name.

```
<Route exact path="/root/folder/subdirectory/test.pdf" component={PDFComponent } />

import pdf from './assets/pdf/test.pdf';

class PDFComponent extends Component {
render(){
return(
 <pdf /> 
 );
}
}
```

This way only that specific url will be accessed.